# Swapping canvas into div

Tags: javascript, canvas, element, swap

Hi I need to exchange one canvas for another. I can't think of how and what it looks like in the browser.
Thank you and I hope you can help me.

```
<div id="juego">
  <canvas width="203" height="256" id="1" class="bloque"></canvas>
  <canvas width="203" height="256" id="2" class="bloque"></canvas>
  <canvas width="203" height="256" id="3" class="bloque"></canvas>
  <canvas width="203" height="256" id="4" class="bloque"></canvas>
</div>
```

I need to exchange one item for another. For example the element in which I clicked next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually move around items using the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) "API". Among other things, HTML elements are `Node`s. On the linked page you will find many things, here I use `firstChild` of the container div, and `insertBefore()`, again of the container div. Apparently it does not mind if a node is inserted before itself, but I only checked with Chrome. (And yes, it is enough to insert, it automatically unlinks the node from its previous location - also, if you want to move something at the end, there is an `appendChild()` for that, with similar auto-remove-from-original-location functionality).

```js
function totop(id){
  let first=container.firstChild;
  let what=document.getElementById(id);
  container.insertBefore(what,first);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="1">one</div>
<div id="2">two</div>
<div id="3">three</div>
</div>
<button onclick="totop(1)">One</button>
<button onclick="totop(2)">Two</button>
<button onclick="totop(3)">Three</button>
```

---

(Old answer)
You can hide/show them via setting their style as

```
document.getElementById("1").style.display="none";
```

to hide and `"block"` (or whatever it was previously) to make it (the first one in this case) appear again.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to exchange one item for another. For example the element in which I clicked next to it.

Comment: @pabloFiscella ok, see the new "proposal"